# Maintain same cookie and session parameters with python requests

Tags: python, session, logging, cookies, python-requests

I am trying to login to a website with python requests, which was done successfully, but when I try to make a `Get` or `Post` request inside my account, to retrieve or post some data, I get server response that I need to login, which I just did in the previous post request succufully, I'm using
the  `session` object, which in theory is supposed to pass automatically cookies sent by the server in the next request, also using proper headers.

```
session = requests.Session()

response = session.get( URL , headers=headers)
# I scrape different logging parameters here and I input my own credentials.

login_data = {"username": 'username', "password": 'password', "csrf_token":token}

response = session.post( URL , login_data, headers=headers)

# Login is successful.

response = session.get(URL_2, headers=headers)
Data = {}
response = session.post(URL_2, Data, headers=headers)

# I get server response that I'm not logged in.
```

The desired behavior of this script is to maintain a consistent logging session and be able to
make requests after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the data to the session (here's an example with a jwt, but it works with cookies too):

```
    if response.status_code == HTTPStatus.OK.value:
        token_info = response.json()["token"]
        session.headers.update(
            {"Authorization": f"Bearer {api.token_info['access_token']}"}
        )
```